# When I call beginTransaction(), must all executions follow in the same scope?

Tags: php

Example:

```
// assume PDO instance here: $dbh

function beginTransaction() {
   global $dbh;
   $dbh->beginTransaction();
}

beginTransaction(); // no typo! called the function above!

$dbh->exec($sql1); // assume $sql1 is there
$dbh->exec($sql2); // assume $sql2 is there

$dbh->commit();
```

What I try to ask: Must a transaction be started and commited inside ONE scope, or can I span a transaction over a wide range of function and method calls? For me it would be logical that the called object doesn't care about the caller. But in Objective-C / Cocoa for example, a UIView animation block IS scope-aware! So I'm confused like a bird in a plane.

Comment: I don't see why it should care, as long as you keep that pointer around it shouldn't matter who is using it, even a different included script.

If the script stops execution then starts up again, or if you put it to sleep for an extended period of time you would lose it.

Just save the sql_query() to some private member for use later and it should have no issue.

Btw, that function call looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One transaction can span over several functions and method calls : the transaction is happening on the database side, and not the PHP side.

A `beginTransaction` in PHP only send "`BEGIN TRAN`" *(or an equivalent)* to the database ; then, it's the database server who is responsible for the transaction -- PHP only send SQL commands.

As a sidenote : you are using this function in your example :

```
function beginTransaction() {
   $dbh->beginTransaction();
}
```

Just note *(not sure if it's because you wrote a quick example, or if it's a real mistake)* that `$dbh` will not exist in that function, unless you declare it as [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global), or pass it as a parameter -- see [Variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in the manual.

Comment: thanks for that sidenote. I hacked the example quickly into the editor :)

Comment: @openfrog : You're welcome :-) I wasn't sure, so I prefered putting a note, just in case :-)

Answer (score 0):

The transaction is bound to the $dbh object, which is a PDO handle, I assume. It is independent of your current scope.

All database queries that are handled by $dbh will be part of that transaction if they are performed after calling $dbh->beginTransaction().