# beginTransaction PDO for class methods

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
   <?php

class dbLayer
{

    //connection from here 

    private $done;

    function __construct(PDO $connection)
    {
        $this->done = $connection;

    }

    public function createAction()
    {
        //create a new  item
    }

    public function readAction()
    {
        //read all the  items
    }

    public function updateAction()
    {

        $sql = $this->done->prepare("UPDATE `sync_log` SET `Sync_Status`=? WHERE `randKey`=?");
        $sql->execute(array(
            $status,
            $randKey
        ));
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        //delete a item
    }

}

?>
```

I want to use `$pdo->beginTransaction();` with class methods.How i use roalback() if my update fail with `updateAction()` method ?

Comment: You catch the exception and run `rollback()`

Comment: can you put an example ?

Comment: what actually you cannot get?

Comment: i have put an answer.Can you check it please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of PDO in classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047264/use-of-pdo-in-classes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I call beginTransaction(), must all executions follow in the same scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966321/when-i-call-begintransaction-must-all-executions-follow-in-the-same-scope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactioned `updateAction()` example:

```
public function updateAction()
{
    try {
        $this->done->beginTransaction();
        $sql = $this->done->prepare("UPDATE `sync_log` SET `Sync_Status`=? WHERE `randKey`=?");
        $sql->execute(array(
            $status,
            $randKey
        ));
        $this->done->commit();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->done->rollback();
    }
}
```

Note that if you want to return the affected rows count you must do that after commit. And you would like to return 0 or `false` on `catch` block after rollback.

Comment: What about the exception? How are you meant to tell something went wrong?

Comment: There's no reason to downvote since it's outside the question... My follow-up comment (based on OP answer that was deleted) is assuming that OP wants to silently fail. If OP had asked that, I'd have rethrowed the exception after rollback.